# Set Processes in a For

Tags: c, fork

I have this function:

```
 void set_background(int n){
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
          fork();
  }
```

This process has to set n processes with a fork. How can I set n processes in a for by doing a fork() to i=0, if we will have the parent and child processes and to i=1 with 4 processes and so on?

Comment: Do you want to continue the loop just as a parent?

Comment: reminds me of a `fork()` bomb

Answer (score 3):

You will need to monitor the return value from `fork()`.

```
void set_background(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         pid_t pid;
         if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
             ...process error...
         else if (pid == 0)
         {
             ...do childish things...
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
    }
    /* If here, must be parent */
}
```

You simplify your flow of control if you ensure that the 'childish' processing never returns.  I've enforced that by the `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` call.

Note that in the original code, the parent forks in the first iteration of the loop, so you have two processes running at the end of the loop.  After the second iteration, both the parent and the child fork, so you've got 4 processes running.  After the Nth iteration, you have 2<sup>N</sup> processes running.  This is seldom the desired effect.  The unbounded loop version of this is called a 'fork bomb' and it capable of bringing a machine to its knees.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `EXIT_FAILURE` and not `EXIT_SUCCESS`?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Because I defined that 'do childish things' should not return; I normally call a function that I call `be_childish();` at that point in the code and if it returns, it is an error.  However, it is also feasible to decide that it is OK for the `be_childish()` code to return and then `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` is OK instead.  Sometimes, the parent code calls `be_parental()`.